integral by parts on matrix integrations: simple example verifications
Suppose I want to perform integration by parts to the following integral:
\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^T \sin(\frac{2\pi}{T}t) A(t) dt, 
\end{equation} where $A(t)$ is a matrix that depends on $t$.
Let $du = \sin(\frac{2\pi}{T}t) dt$ and $v = A(t)$, which gives $u = \frac{-T}{2\pi}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}t)$ and $dv = A'(t) dt$. Then, using the standard form of the integration by parts, we have
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{-T}{2\pi}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}t) A(t)|_0^T - \int_0^T \frac{-T}{2\pi}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}t) A'(t) dt \\
= \frac{-T}{2\pi} (A(T) - A(0)) + \int_0^T \frac{T}{2\pi}\cos(\frac{2\pi}{T}t) A'(t) dt.
\end{equation} Are these steps correct? If something's wrong, I am happy to be corrected and learn what is my mistake!

In your case, the elements of the matrices do not affect each other at all. You can express the element at row $i$ and column $j$ of the integral as$$
I_{i,j} = \int_0^T\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}t\right)A_{i,j}(t)\mathrm dt
$$where $A_{i,j}(t)$ is the elemenet of matrix $A(t)$ at row $i$ and column $j$. Now $A_{i,j}$ is a standard function of type $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and you can therefore apply any integration rules as you are used to.
To answer your question: Yes, it is correct.
